# Can a single link be accessed using multiple random QR code generator or can have one time QR code that expires after sometime?

Tags: html, web, hyperlink, project

I am making an attendence systemn and I want it such that a everytime a random QR Code displays on board and the students scanning it can fill a form that stores information and I can access it later to mark it on the final list.
What Coding knowledge I need to have to make this project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.